# Chromium Extended FrameWork (CEF) debug window not running

Tags: web, chromium-embedded

I wanted to run the Chromium Extended FrameWork debug window and I get the following error message in the window:

Error -2 when loading url chrome-devtools://devtools/devtools.html?docked=false&toolbarColor=rgba(223,223,223,1)&textColor=rgba(18,50,114,1)

Has anyone ever received this before and know what it could mean?

Comment: Are you using the official cefclient sample project? Which version of CEf3 are you using? Which OS, OSX or Windows ? Give more information would get more useful advices.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to open the debug window? Note the URL you are using can only be used when you open the window on your own, not using javascript's `openWindow`.